# electrical switch and outlet issue

Tags: electrical

I have a room in my house with both a dimmer switch and a flip switch. The flip switch controls the ceiling light and fan, and the dimmer controls the outlet by the entrance. It seems now we cannot use the outlet (for the tv) and the light at the same time. Does anyone know what could be happening or how to fix it?

The breakers dont trip when we try to turn on both.

Comment: What do you mean by "It seems now we cannot use the outlet (for the tv) and the light at the same time"?  If you turn on the light does the outlet lose voltage?

Comment: It is a code violation and a REALLY bad idea to have a dimmer control a wall receptacle.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you’re using a light and TV on a dimmer switch controlled Plug (outlet)

If so that is a extremely bad idea as this is totally unsuited for TVs, Stereos, Computers, and other equipment. Equipment of this type will likely kill the electronic switch (triac) inside the dimmer switch and will put the attached appliances into a condition where they are likely to be destroyed when the dimmer is set at anything less than 100% on.

Solutions:

1. Put TV on different non controlled outlet (You will still have to replace the defective Dimmer switch)
2. You can if you want to keep the on off switch, remove the dimmer and put a regular light wall switch
3. The best would be to remove the Dimmer/light switch all together (After shutting power off from Breaker) and connect the switching wires together(NOT THE GROUNG)and cap, Then put a blank wall plate on.

Comment: Simply removing the switch could violate NEC 210.70(A)(1), unless there's another switch controlled lighting outlet in the room.